# How to migrate data when updating an ionic/cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, migration

i am curious about best practices concerning (hybrid) app updates. In my current case, i am updating an app for the first time. There are new and also changed functionalities, e.g.

- new / updated images
- updated and deleted data for a local sqlite db
- new / updated data for localstorage

I just couldn't find any guides how to accomplish that migrations (once). I could always do it quick and dirty, but i want some future prove technics, because this will be the first of many updates coming...

For my node.js applications e.g. i use https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate. I have the feeling, that i probably will recreate that logic inside an angular service...

Comment: heyo @chris did you find a good solution to this?

Comment: i ended up creating an update script containing tasks per update version, which saved the current version to a file. on startup i compare the app version to the version in this file and execute the delta of upgrade tasks